# Dynamic schema in Table API

Tags: apache-flink, tableau-api, flink-streaming, flink-sql

I have Flink Job that is using Table API, Input log in the Flink Job has a diff log schema, let’s say
log1 has {x=1,y=“abc”,z=true}
log2 has {x=1,a=“yu”,b=false} in future I can have other fields

As far as I have explored I need fix schema, But in this example I can not make schema correct, So how can I make dynamic schema on the each rule?

Thank you so much, I highly appreciate your reply